# Python: does it matter where I save properties?

Tags: python

When I create a new property, I do something like this:

```
bpy.types.WindowManager.something = StringProperty(...
```

Or maybe:

```
bpy.types.Scene.something = StringProperty(...
```

etc. Could someone explain what the difference is and what are the best practices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blender's Custom properties can be attached to selected blender classes.

- All data block types
- Bones and Pose Bones
- Sequence Strips

Where to place a property really depends on you usecase. If the property is tells something (or enhances) something that is related to Materials why not add it to the material self, so it is easier to find.

Best way to approach this is: Find the most detailed class where it tells something about a single instance of that class. If the property is shared over multiple instances of that class you can move it to a higher level like:

- Armature for Bones and PoseBones
- WindowManager for Scenes
- Scene for most other classes

When placing it with Objects it is also important to find if it is part of the Object (placement in 3d scene) or part of its data (Mesh etc).

At the end it is just normal software design and knowing how Blender is stuctured

Comment: Would note that window manager ID properties are not saved `context.window_manager["something"] = "not saved"` . Hence `context.window_manager.something`  will resort to default value every time blender is closed and opened. Useful for UI props IMO..